# Synchronize the commit from master code to the branch code avoiding merging conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, github, merge

I currently have a git repository, where I have a C++ project.I wanted to add some new feature in this project . So I created a branch and added my new code. In the meantime there were lots of commits on master code. Now I want to commit master code to my current branch code to keep branch as a clone of master with newly added feature. But using the time of **git merge** command I get merge conflict.

Is there any way to synchronize the commit from master code to branch code avoiding merge conflicts ?

Comment: If git can't figure out how to merge your code, you cannot magically combine the two versions without merging them.

Comment: Periodically rebasing from master can help, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid merge conflicts with distributed version control is to make sure your branches never drift too far from master.  Regularly pull the most recent changes, and rebase if your branch is local.

No matter what you do, however, you're bound to have merge conflicts eventually.  As @SLaks mentioned, there's no magic bullet in this situation.  You simply need to look at your changes as well as the upstream ones to decide what's right, resolve the conflict, commit it and move on.